# How to return Option[List]?

Tags: scala

I have a case class like this:

```
case class ColorDetails(color: Color = Color(),
                         shades: List[Shades] = Nil)
```

I have below which works fine:

```
  final case class GetColorDetails(replyTo: ActorRef[Option[ColorDetails]])
      extends ColorCommand
  ....
    case GetColorDetails(replyTo) =>
      if (state.color.isEmpty) {
        replyTo ! None
      } else {
        replyTo ! Some(ColorDetails(state.color, state.shades))
      }
      Effect.none
```

However, now I am trying to implement `GetColors` as below:

```
  final case class GetColors(replyTo: ActorRef[Option[List[ColorDetails]]])
    extends ColorCommand
  ....
    case GetColors(replyTo) =>
      if (state.color.isEmpty) {
        replyTo ! None
      }
      else {
        replyTo ! List[ColorDetails(state.color, state.shades)]
      }
      Effect.none
```

But I'm getting error: `Type mismatch, expected Option[List[ColorDetails]], actual: List[ColorDetails]`

How can I fix this?

If I try to return `Some` I get `']' expected but '(' found` error

```
scala> case class Color(color: String)
defined class Color

scala> Some(List[Color("red")])
<console>:1: error: ']' expected but '(' found.
       Some(List[Color("red")])
                      ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return an `Option[List[ColorDetails]]`, you can do it as follows:

```
Some(myList)
```

where `myList` is a `List[ColorDetails]`, and simply `None`, for an empty Option.

Of course, depending on the application, it might be unnecessary to expect a list wrapped inside an option (since an empty list already may be used to indicate the fact that there is nothing there), but that would depend on your design.

Comment: I'm new to scala. I tried doing `Some(List[Color("red")])` but I get an error `error: ']' expected but '(' found`. I've updated the question with the output

Comment: Try `Some(List(Color("red")))` instead. In Scala, square brackets are used for types.

Comment: Notice that this is equivalent to writing `Some(List[Color](Color("red")))`, but the type is already inferred from the argument so the type definition `[Color]` becomes unnecessary.